# Creating a menu like structure (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I wanted to create a menu of items that the bot can do and then the user can select the operation to perform.

For example:
When I say `+Menu` then the bot shows something like:

```
1. Time in NY
2. Movies currently running
3. Sports News
```

Then I wanted to take the user's input (1,2 or 3) and then based on their selection, the bot will execute the task.
But I am not sure how to read the user's input after the command (+Menu) and wanted to ask for help.

Comment: You could use message or reaction collectors. Check them out here: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#message-collectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a `message collector`. See the docs [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html)

Personally I would create an embed with the options in it e.g.

```js
const menuEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("Menu")
.addFields(
  { name: "1.", value: "Time in NY"},
  { name: "2.", value:  "Movies currently running"},
  { name: "3.", value:  "Sports News"}
);

message.channel.send(menuEmbed).then(() => {
  const filter = (user) => {
    return user.author.id === message.author.id //only collects messages from the user who sent the command
  };
  
  try {
  let collected = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 15000, errors: ['time'] });
      let choice = collected.first().content; //takes user input and saves it
  
      //do execution here
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    return message.channel.send(`:x: Setup cancelled - 0 messages were collected in the time limit, please try again`).then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 4000 }));
  };    
});
```

Then use a collector to let the user choose an option.

Bear in mind this is using `async/await` and must be in an `async` function.